# Simfony2-Twig: Render only a single part of a template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a homepage wich dynamically loads a bunch of "posts" (similar to facebook wall).

There is the option to follow a post, but when someone clicks on the follow button, which has a counter on following people, I need to reload all the homepage to update this value. How can I update just the part corresponding to the post? Actually the post is in an extern hmtl.twig file which I render from the homepage code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
         {% for sueno in suenos %}
            {% if loop.index0 is even %}
                {{ render(controller('SuenoBundle:Default:suenoFrontend', { 'sueno': sueno } )) }}
            {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
       </div><!--/col-md-6-->
```

This is the controller:

```
public function suenoFrontendAction($sueno)
{
        return $this->render('SuenoBundle:Default:suenoFrontend.html.twig', array(
        'sueno' => $sueno));
}
```

This the post html file:

```
                <h4 class="text-center nombre-usuario">{{ sueno.usuario.nombre ~ ' ' ~ sueno.usuario.apellido }}</h4>   
                  {% if sueno.necesitaAyuda == 1 %}
                    <p class="text-center texto-sueno"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/SOS.png') }}" width="25" height="25" alt="SOS" /></p>       
                  {% endif %}                    
                  {% if sueno.rol == 'foto' %}
                          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageModal" data-image="{{ asset('upload/images/' ~ sueno.fotoLink) }}" onclick="verFoto(this.getAttribute('data-image'))"><img src="{{ asset('upload/images/' ~ sueno.fotoLink) }}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image"></a>
                  {% elseif sueno.rol == 'video' %}
                          <div class="video-container"><iframe src="{{ sueno.linkVideo }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
                  {% endif %}
                          <h4 class="text-center titulo-sueno">{{ sueno.titulo }}</h4>
                          <h4 class="text-center quepido-sueno">{{ sueno.quePido }}</h4>
                          <p class="text-center texto-sueno info">{{ sueno.texto }}</p>   
                          <br>
                        <div>
                            {% set size = sueno.usuariosColaboradores | length %}
                            {% set size2 = sueno.usuariosSeguidores | length %}
                            <p class="text-center opciones-sueno">
                            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/colaboradores.png') }}" width="20" height="20" alt="Colaboradores" /> {{ size }}
                            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/punto.png') }}" width="5" height="5" alt="punto" />
                            <a href="{{ path('seguir', { 'suenoid': sueno.id }) }}"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/seguidores.png') }}" width="20" height="20" alt="Seguidores" /></a> {{ size2 }}
                            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/punto.png') }}" width="5" height="5" alt="punto" />
                            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/compartir.png') }}" width="20" height="20" alt="Compartir" />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    <hr>
```

Here you can see the action correpsonding to follow a post(its in the previous code, I remark the line):

```
<a href="{{ path('seguir', { 'suenoid': sueno.id }) }}"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/seguidores.png') }}" width="20" height="20" alt="Seguidores" /></a> {{ size2 }}
```

size2 value is the one to update. the controller called when clicking here is this(and where I suppose the failure is):

```
    public function seguirAction($suenoid)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $usuario = $this->getUser();

    $sueno = $em->getRepository('SuenoBundle:Sueno')->findOneBy(array('id' => $suenoid));

    $usuario->getSuenosSigue()->add($sueno);  
    $em->persist($usuario);
    $em->flush();

  // $suenos = $em->getRepository('SuenoBundle:Sueno')->findBy(array('usuario' => $usuario->getId()));

    //esto hay que cambiarlo entero para conseguir los sueños apropiados
        //return $this->render('EstructuraBundle:Home:home.html.twig', array('suenos'=> $suenos , 'usuario' => $usuario));
                return $this->render('SuenoBundle:Default:suenoFrontend.html.twig', array(
        'sueno' => $sueno));
}
```

The thing is that when this render happens, the post fills the full page.

What I want is just to re-render this post in the homepage

Comment: You should work with a JS front-end framework and use Symfony2 to provide a backend API.

Comment: Even if I use Twig, the forntend is mainly made using Bootstrap. Does that help?

Comment: bootstrap is a CSS framework, not a JS frond-end framework. You have to use AJAX or something like that, and them you need to provide an API with Symfony2 and to make it all easier to maintain, I recommend to use a front-end framework. Btw, Twig and Bootstrap have nothing to do with eachother...

Comment: Let me tell that using BootstrapBraincrafted Bundle it really worked well the use of bootstrap and twig. I am really happy with it. On the other side, I found twig,js(http://jmsyst.com/libs/twig.js) Which I think its appropriate for what I want.